# Sequence Limits in an Interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If the $lim_n s_n = L$ and for every $n$, $s_n$ is in the interval $[a,b]$, then $L$ is also in $[a,b]. $

$Proof$ First we show that $L \le b.$ Suppose not, say $L\gt b$ and let $\epsilon = L -b \gt 0.$ Then the inequality $|s_n -L| \lt \epsilon$ implies that
$$s_n \gt L - \epsilon =L - (L-b)=b$$

Thus $s_n$ would not be in $[a,b].$

This is as far as I have gotten and I an stuck on where to go with the proof.

After finishing this proof I then need to show by example that the stronger assumption is, that $s_n$ is in $(a,b)$ doe $not$ guarantee that $L$ is also in $(a,b)$

I would greatly appreciate any help but I genuinely want to understand the truths behind these proofs and statements.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $L<a$. Then let $\epsilon=a-L$. Since $|s_n-L|<\epsilon$, then we know that $s_n<\epsilon +L= a-L +L=a$.

Thus $s_n$ is less than $a$. That is, $s_n$ is not in the interval [$a,b$]. Again a contradiction.

Thus we have that $L$ must be in [$a,b$].

In order to answer the second part of the question, just show a counter example. Think of the sequence given by $s_n =\frac{1}{n}$. This sequence lies inside the (open) interval $(0,1)$, but the limit of the sequence is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct and a can easily be adapted to prove the lower bound.

Alternatively, you can use the fact that $s_n \ge a$ is equivalent to $-s_n \le -a$. By the already proven part of the theorem, this implies $-L = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} -s_n \le -a$, i.e. $L \ge a$.

To show that the stronger assertion doesn't hold, simply find a sequence in $(a, b)$ that converges to $b$.